# Can i replace the JDBC logic with hibernate afterwards

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jdbc, spring-mvc

I am building a website with spring MVC. As I am new to Java EE, I'm finding it difficult to apply everything at once.

So, is it possible that I can start building the app with simple JDBC and spring and then later replace that with hibernate?

Will the shift be easier so I should learn hibernate first and then start with the website?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only with (at least) two preconditions:

- you completely abstract database access in a DAO layer. Each DAO should have an interface, and a `JdbcXDao` implementation. Later you can add the same `HibernateXDao`
- your DAO should return domain objects. No result sets or statements should go out of the dao. For example, if you need to get the messages by a given user, you can write `List<Message> messages = dao.getMessages(user)`.

If either of the above is not met, you will have hard time migrating to hibernate.

But it's likely that you won't have the nerves to change the whole DAO layer afterwards, so spend some more time on hibernate and start directly with it.

Comment: +1 - adding to the result sets etc that should not go out of the DAO, also make sure that the DAO interface does not declare any exceptions like SQLException. I've often seen people build "technology neutral" DAO interfaces, but still sprinkle them with SQLExceptions, IOExeptions, etc.

Answer (score 6):

If **JDBC** is all you need to build your application, I don't see any benefits on rewriting everything **just to use Hibernate**.

Hibernate's main purpose is to save you from the hassle of writing repetitive INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT code with plain **JDBC**. And you could mix some PLAIN-JDBC with Hibernate and add **ORM** to your application gradually if you feel you need to.

Having said that, for simple database stuff, of database stuff that needs complicated queries, I would pick plain JDBC 1000 times before I go into a Hibernate based solution.

Comment: Testing will be possible with Hibernate. You will be able to use an in-memory database (H2, HSQLDB..) for unit tests.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course you can.  It can even be easy to do if you write it properly.

Start your persistence tier with interfaces; only allow your clients to call objects that are interface reference types.  Put a JDBC implementation behind them today; tomorrow you can switch to a Hibernate implementation and your clients will be none the wiser.  That's the beauty of interfaces.

Something like this:

```
package persistence;

public interface FooDao
{
    List<Foo> find();
    Foo find(Long id);
    void saveOrUpdate(Foo foo);
    void delete(Foo foo);
}
```

One important thing to note: this interface is dealing only with your model objects, not SQL.  The manner in which your persistence layer deals with the relational database starts with the object model.  This is a requirement for Hibernate.  It immediately becomes mandatory for your JDBC implementation if your intent is to be able to replace it with Hibernate someday.